# In the present tense, can I use "ought to have" where "have" means "to possess"?

Tags: tenses, present-tense, auxiliary-verbs

I'm not a native English speaker.

All the examples of "ought to have" in my grammar book are in the past tense.  But can I use it in the present tense to say that someone probably has something?

> I **ought to have time** tomorrow to meet you (I should have time tomorrow to meet you).

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. **Proofreading questions ("Is this right?", "Are there any mistakes?") is off-topic in this community**. I deleted the question. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: @Rathony This is not a proofreading question. stegaman is asking about a specific usage. The question might be more appropriate in ELL, though.

Comment: @GoDucks It depends on how you define it. And this question could be borderline on-topic. I just posted a comment to ask stegaman to learn more about this community and haven't close-voted it yet. Let's see how others respond to this question.

Comment: @Rathony What do you mean you "deleted the question"?

Comment: @GoDucks I deleted "Is the sentence correct?" You could see the revision history by clicking on "edited X minutes ago" right above Rathony. It shows what has been changed and deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. Just one example from the *Oxford English Dictionary* (OED):

> 1796   J. Lawrence Philos. & Pract. Treat. Horses I. vi. 305   **The Thames-street carts ought to have either four wheels, or three.**

Example from popular television

> [Everybody Ought to Have a Maid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everybody_Ought_to_Have_a_Maid) (2009)

Just google "[ought to have a](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ought%20to%20have%20a%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)" and start reading the pages of results.

And so, yes your sentence is correct.

Comment: "ought to have a" brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

You can use *ought* in the present tense to say that someone probably has something.

[Definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ought) of *ought*:

> Used to indicate a desirable or expected state.
>
> e.g., *He ought to be able to take the initiative.*

But you cannot use the phrase *ought have* with the present or future tense.

[Definition](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/ought-to-have-done-something) of the idiom, *ought to have (done something)*:

> Used when you realize that someone did not do the right thing in the past.
>
> e.g., *You ought to have listened to the warnings.*
>
> e.g., *I know I ought not to have taken the money.*

So, your example sentence is confusing. If you are using "ought have" idiomatically, the sentence does not make sense, because it means:

> I regret not to have time tomorrow to meet you.

But, if you are using "ought have" in the literal sense, it does make sense:

> I will probably have time tomorrow to meet you.

To avoid confusion, I would phrase the sentence in other words, like you wrote:

> I should have time tomorrow to meet you.

In general, try to avoid using idioms in the literal sense (even if it is obvious based on context that you do not mean the idiom), because people may not understand that you are not using the idiom.